# ar_markers - import coordinates python file

Tags: ros, ar-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I use the ar_kinect package to recognize the ar_markers.

I like to import the coordinates in the python file so I have to initialise the Markers which I use at the begin of the file and found this example:

self.markers = { 0: ["ILS_OFFICE",-0.4064,-1.22,0.6858,-1.570796,0,0] }

My question is, what are the six numbers after the name from the marker (here: "ILS_OFFICE") and where I get this information for my marker?

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50318/ar_markers---import-coordinates-python-file/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The 6-tuple you refer to is the 3D position/orientation:

[x,y,z,theta_x,theta_y,theta_z]

(theta_i means angle around the i axis)

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0